# Configuring the GRUB cryptodisk unlock screen

Tags: themes, grub-efi, cryptsetup

I run GRUB with LUKS. So I have GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y and my /etc/crypttab all set-up.

When I start up it shows me a message like "Enter password to unlock [crypto disk name]:", at which point I enter my password and the boot process proceeds to my login manager.

I am looking for a way to modify this screen. Specifically I want to remove the "Enter password" message entirely and replace it with some ASCII art. I will know that it is the password prompt, and if someone else is accessing my computer and gets confused by it, well... all the better.

I have looked in the [GNU Grub Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Simple-configuration.html) already. The section here says,

> ‘GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK’
> If set to ‘y’, grub-mkconfig and grub-install will check for encrypted disks and generate additional commands needed to access them during boot. Note that in this case unattended boot is not possible because GRUB will wait for passphrase to unlock encrypted container.

This leads me to believe there is some interaction between GRUB and cryptsetup to create the message. Unsurprisingly, cryptsetup documentation does not include a section on configuring these.

So, I'm at a bit of a dead-end, and I could use some guidance. I would be surprised if I were the first person to want to try this.